# Calculate bounds of gameobject without Mesh, Renderer or Collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to calculate the bounds of an object when it does not have Renderer, Mesh or Collider components.
[image]

Inspector for object: [image]

Inspector for child object: [image]

Comment: If an object does not have Renderer, Mesh or Collider components, it is just a single point, how does a point have its bounds?

Comment: The parent object just groups the child objects and the child objects have Mesh Filter and Mesh Renderder. Here I want to calculate the bounds of the parent object. I updated the photo on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get all child renderers (or colliders), then unite all of them.

```
var renderers = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
var bounds = renderers[0].bounds;
for (var i = 1; i < renderers.Length; ++i)
    bounds.Encapsulate(renderers[i].bounds);
```